# List reversion inspired by Python

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax

In python, if you wish to reverse a list, here is the trick:

```
range(10)[::-1]  => [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Note:  `list[start:end:steps]` is the slice method in python. The above code omitted the first two arguments.

It rings a bell in *Mathematica*:

```
Part[list, Span[start, end, step]] <=> list[[start;; end;; step]]
```

However this isn't gonna work in MMA (or not yet? since mine is still MMA 7)

```
Range[10][[;; ;; -1]]
```

> `Part::take:` Cannot take positions 1 through -1 in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}. >>
>     `Part[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, 1 ;; All ;; -1]`

This error message gave clues to what happened.
When step length is negative, the start index should be greater than the end one - no matter in python or MMA syntax.

The problem why this didn't work lies in the omitted arguments. MMA filled them with **1** and **All** and then got stuck. By contrast python smartly exchanged the two.

My actual question in this is: **How can I can look into the default values  /optional arguments of a built-in function like `Span`?** I can't find it in the documentations.

---

Give another look at the fun code: `range(10)[::-1]`

My implementation of this it to modify the definitions

```
Unprotect[Span, Part];
Part[x_List, Span[1, All, k_]] /; k < 0 := Part[x, Span[All, 1, k]];
Protect[Span, Part]

(*behold lol*)

Range[10][[;; ;; -1]]
(* {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1} *)
```

To clear the modifications:

```
Unprotect[Span, Part]; Clear[Span, Part]; Protect[Span, Part]
```

or

```
CompoundExpression@@ Through[{Unprotect, Clear, Protect}[Span, Part]]
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't want to use the `Reverse` command?

Comment: Nope, it's a just-because-I-could situation. And "Reverse@" is still shorter than "[[;;;;-1]]". :p

Comment: This works: `Range[10][[10 ;; 1 ;; -1]]`.  It's not an idiom I've used, but found it pretty easily in the documentation.

Comment: And in case your list is of unknown length, you can change @MarkMcClure's idiom to `[[-1 ;; 1 ;; -1]]` to reverse it

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `Range[9, 0, -1]`?

Comment: IMO your python trick is an oddity. Evan an experienced python programmer may not expect that result.  Why would you want behavior that only serves to make code hard to understand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your question: In this case you could just type a *fake* `Span` call and keep it unevaluated. When you then look at the fullForm you see:

```
Hold[list[[ ;; ;;-1]]]//FullForm

(* Hold[Part[list,Span[1,All,-1]]] *)
```

what you actually called: `Span[1,All,-1]`.

Since you now know what happens, you can catch, when someone calls `Part[list_, Span[1, All, -1]` and use `Reverse` to give the reversed list

```
Unprotect[Span];
Span /: Part[list_, Span[1, All, -1]] := Reverse[list];
Protect[Span]
```

and now your simple example works as expected

```
Range[10][[;;;;-1]]
(* {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1} *)
```

Comment: Pardon me, but isn't this basically already in the question?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The question was, how to find out to what `Span[[;;;;-1]]` is evaluated. I updated my answer later to show how to use `Upvalues` and `Reverse`. And yes, all details were already implicitly given in the question. The only part I added was how get to what `list[[;;;;-1]]` is evaluated.

Comment: is the generalization to arbitrary negative increments Reverse[list][[;;;;Abs[inc]]] or Reverse[list[[;;;;Abs[inc]]]] ?   Anybody sure without trying it..?

Answer (score 12):

Your python idiom can be implemented in *Mathematica* using `Part` and `Span` as:

```
Range[10][[-1;;1;;-1]]
(* {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1} *)
```

which is very similar to your python command, and doesn't require you to unprotect either `Span` or `Part`.

Comment: This is nice, but somehow I don't think the OP is unaware of this as he knew how to write the equivalent.  Rather, this question is about low-level defaults, is it not?  Isn't `Span` just an illustration?

Comment: I don't think they're aware of negative indices, and what they wrote — `[[;; ;; -1]]` — is not an equivalent. I don't see this as low level defaults question, because no defaults are being used here. `;;` is explicit for "all elements" (`;;` and `All` are mentioned in the `Part` docs), and this is just a matter of being confused by seeing `1` and `All` in the fullform used in the error. In other words, I don't think this has to do with mysterious defaults in the same way that `Slot[1]` for `#` is not using a hidden default of 1.

Comment: Okay.  By the way I meant `Span[All, 1, -1]` as the equivalent, which he used.